# Including a djVu files with pgf/pdfpages package

Tags: pdfpages, pgf-core

Is it possible to manipulate `.djVu` files with `pgf` and/or `pdfpage` packages; and produce a `pdf`?

Comment: I think the answer here will be 'no' as DjVu files are not PDF files, so will need to be converted,

Comment: I agree with Joseph and I think it should be an answer.

Comment: In ubuntu you can do the following (taken from an online forum) Step - 1 : Goto Synaptic Package Manager (System - Administration - Synaptic Package Manager)
Step - 2 : Install DJview4
Step - 3 : Run DJview (Applications - Graphics - DJView4)
Step - 4 : Open your .djvu document
Step - 5 : Menu - Export As: PDF

Comment: You don't need to install something special. Evince can open DjVu files (compile-time option) and save them to PDF or PS.

Answer (score 6):

The DjVu format is different to PDF, and so there is no way to 'slot in' a DjVu file inside a larger PDF. Thus you will need to convert your DjUv to PDF format, then include from the PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You can in fact get a djvu file nested in a PDF container if you `\usepackage{attachfile}`.  But this may not be what you're after, because when your resulting PDF is rendered, it will not display the djvu files inline.  At best, the PDF can show a thumb tac such that when a user clicks it, the djvu file is either displayed separately or a prompt asks for an action on the djvu file.

Comment: The question was about *manipulation* of `djVu` files not only showing nor attaching them.